# Is there an event payload when adding ms teams app to org?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

If I upload a custom app that has a messaging bot to an MS Teams org (through admin center), is there an event payload that gets sent to the bot messaging payload that lets me know that the app/bot is added to that MS Teams tenant?

Something similar to installationUpdate event: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=dotnet#installation-update-event but for adding app to org (this payload event is sent for when users add app to their own MS Teams space)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no event for this.

Having it installed in a tenant doesn’t do anything except making it available for users to install. And without a user installing it, you cannot interact with the bot.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways the app could be added to the org: either (a) by them adding the package manually, in which case presumably you gave it to them, so you should know about it, or (b) by your app being in the public App Store. In this 2nd case, you'll know it's been installed into the tenant by using the same  `installationUpdate` event you mentioned - you can store an entry somewhere on your infrastructure (e.g. a database or otherwise) that tracks which tenants have installed the bot ever before in any channel, and if nothing is found for the incoming tenant id, it must be new.

Comment: Sure thing. If this helped you, please Mark as Answer or Upvote so others with a similar issue can find it in future.